# What is the correct grade of Magic cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I didn't find any questions regarding card grading in here, I hope it's fine anyways.

I was browsing a secondary market today and noticed that [Scrying Sheets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bScrying%20Sheets%5d) underwent a price increase, probably because of Modern Horizons. I went through my collection and eventually found one. Now I'm not that experienced when it comes to grading. I mean I know when a card is near mint and when it's not but other than that i find it hard to distinguish the range from *Good - Played*. Since I wanna sell it I'll have to set a grade for it. My first guess was *good* but the damage on the bottom right corner makes me concerned.

[image]

[image]

By what criteria are Magic cards graded, and how would they be applied to this card?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be helpful to future users; questions about specific items are highly likely to be opinion-based rather than have a single verifiable and objective answer.

Comment: I dont agree. One could help with an answer that provides a good method of grading cards in general, this doesn't have to be restricted to this card.

Comment: Then why not ask the question that doesn't require dealing with the specific card in order to actually be answered?

Comment: @Nij, Are you claiming there no criteria to establish the grade of a card and that the grading system is useless? I'm not knowledgeable in this area, but I find that highly unlikely. A *lot* of money rides on the quality of such items. If instead there are established criteria for grading cards as I suspect, then it's not opinion based, and there's no basis for closing this question.

Comment: No, I'm saying that trying to grade this specific card is neither helpful to anybody else (against the point of SE) and still requires more opinion on how they apply. But if you're wanting to strawman the actual criticism just to defend keeping this open, go ahead.

Comment: @Nij, Fixed the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [TrollTraderCards](https://www.trolltradercards.com/faq):

> Near Mint / Mint:  ­Cards in NM-Mint condition show minimal to no wear
>   from shuffling or general play
>
> Light Play: ­ Minor scuffing, drawing (including signatures or stamps)
>   or slight bending.
>
> Moderate Play: ­ May show any amount of wear, and any type of wear,
>   but usually still legal for tournament play once sleeved
>
> Heavy Play: ­ As moderate play, although much more excessive. May not
>   be legal for tournament use, even when sleeved.

But for a more in-depth I would use Star City Games's guide as it provides with you example images. You can find that [here](https://www.starcitygames.com/content/cardconditions).

I would grade your card (without personally looking at it) between PL and HP using Star City Games's grading system, as I can't see if the card has much dirt in it but has that white spot near the top on the left. If it is just a blemish and the bottom and the card is also clean, then PL, if the card has some gunk in it overall, then HP.

Comment: considering your answer I'll grade it as played, thank you.